# Correctly converting to timezone from UTC in MySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, utc, timezone-offset

I see that a stored date value in phpmyadmin is 2020-03-03. In PHP, I set the default timezone to UTC and the user's timezone to America/New_York:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$userTimeZone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
```

I retrieve my date from the database, set the timezone on the date, and make it into a string. It now equals a day earlier. (03-02-2020)

```
$dateNeeded = new DateTime($row['dateNeeded']); 
$dateNeeded->setTimeZone($userTimeZone);
$dateNeededStr = $dateNeeded->format('m-d-Y');
```

What did I do incorrectly here?

Comment: If you have no time component in your stored date, isn't it supposed to turn out an earlier date in a different timezone if that timezone is behind the one of the stored date?

Comment: I have no idea. Is that the problem here? The data type in MySQL is "date".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not incorrect. Your date is stored without the time component, which means when you put it in a `DateTime` constructor, it will be created as midnight (`$dateNeeded = new DateTime($row['dateNeeded'])` will have the value of `2020-03-03 00:00:00`.

That's in UTC timezone because you defined it so at the start. So when you change the timezone, it will move back (as New York is UTC - 5) and gain the value of `2020-03-02 19:00:00`.

Since you're only outputting the date in your format (and not the time), it comes out as a day early.

Comment: How do I handle formatting it and ignore the time component? Maybe just don't assign a timezone with setTimeZone?

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` because MySQL server will use server timezone not UTC,

**In example,**

Your server time zone is GMT +2

And you set your server timezone to GMT +0;

Then you read your date on database which stored on GMT + 2 time zone

When you try to convert it to other timezone, e.g. GMT + 5,

It will shift 7 hour not 5 hour